# Can a Google Form spawn another Google Form

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible, (via Appscript), for one Google Form "Form A" to create and open another Google Form "Form B" during the onSubmit trigger of Form A?

I want to ask a user how many entries they want to make on Form A.  Then I want Form A to effectively "call" Form B for each entry desired.

I can create the form dynamically or FormApp.openByUrl() but they both fail with an error.  I'm beginning to wonder if a Form cannot be subordinate to a Form?

Any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your form with the onSubmit trigger of your source Google form.

```
function createGoogleForm() {
 const sourceFormId = "xxyy";
 const file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFormId);
 return file.getUrl();
}
```